# JavaScript And CSS for listing menu

Tags: javascript, css

I have used a Javascript for listing element
And I have set background image in CSS and that is repeated none as follow:

```
#expList li {
    line-height:140%;
    text-indent:0px;
    background-position: 1px 1px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Now I want to set `cursor: pointer` on this background image only. any trick?

Comment: You should place this background-images in a separate element

Comment: Yes put background images in a container #expList and put background and cursor there.

Comment: @Matthijs like in inline ... r8?

Comment: Thanx for help. That I know but I was interested if any Idea for using this like this onl.

Comment: Why because image is dependent on classes. It is changing variably on change of class in li element or ul element

Answer (score 0):

CSS rules are applied to entire elements, not part of them. So no. You'll need to create another element of the dimensions you want and assign your pointer rule to that.

Comment: May be I can use JavaScript or something if any?